# Tab Group Favorites always greyed out in desktop Safari

Tags: safari, tabs, bookmarks

When I launch Safari on the desktop, the tab group favorites are always greyed out. I have to use `Edit Bookmarks` and double-click on a bookmark and only then are the Tab Group Favorites no longer greyed out.

Here is a screenshot of the issue
[image: Tab Group Favorites greyed out in desktop Safari]

Comment: What exactly does the screenshot show?

Comment: The Tab Group Favorites greyed out. Those three items are unselectable